# Help me to improve grammar of this question

Tags: editing, grammar

I asked a question on stackoverflow.com some time ago.

Would you please notify me possible grammatical problems of my question?

And if possible give me tips to ask question with better expression.
 
This is my question :

> I have very similar senario in my
>   application. I want to find best
>   practice in this senario. 
> Mostly I
>   have a master GridView In my page.
>   this master Gridview may perform these
>   actions : 
>  Add new record
>
> 1. Adding new record
> 2. Deleting a record
> 3. Searching data that binded in GridView
> 4. Displaying detail Information about selected record in GridView.
>
> So for adding new record I'm using a
>   dialog or other similar jQuery plugins
>   
>  For Deleting records I'm making
>   full postback to refresh data after
>   confirm dialog and sometimes I'm
>   putting target GridView in an ASP.NET
>   UpdatePanel to prevent full postback.
>   
> Also for searching data I had to
>   making full postback I think I have no
>   way to doing this action without
>   postback (Consider complex gridview)
>   
>  And for displaying more detail
>   information about current record
>   without postback I have 2 ways :
>
> 1. I'm using to loading an ASP.NET usercontrol  asynchronous, but regard
>      to [this][1] thread I'm not able to
>      doing ServerSide actions with postback
>      because of some unsolvable reasons.
> 2. another way that often launched my work is this : for example I want to
>      display a listbox and a treeview about
>      a record in jQuery Dialog. I putted
>      them in an updatepanel and I'm writing
>      binding codes in a server side button
>      and hiding this button,then I'm
>      triggering click event of Binding
>      button in OnOpen event of jQuery
>      Dialog. 
>     due My softwares are
>      running in local and ethernet I don't
>      care SEO. 
>     As I'm a novice
>      programmer please share your
>      expriences with me, note me where I'm
>      wrong(maybe everywhere !) and where I
>      can using better ways. thanks.   [1]:
>      https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519450/postback-in-loaded-asp-net-usercontrol-with-jquery

Comment: Vote to close for not follow the guidelines established for critiques on Meta: http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/166/what-are-the-guidelines-for-asking-for-a-critique-of-my-work and http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/181/policy-change-writing-critique-questions-now-welcome

Comment: Please [discuss on meta whether or not this recent guideline change](http://meta.writers.stackexchange.com/questions/301/should-we-allow-grammar-proofreading-questions) is something the community wants before closing.

Comment: Per the consensus from the discussion, proof-reading questions are off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

> What are the best practices to use in
>   this senario? I have a master
>   `GridView` in my page which performs
>   these actions:
>
> - Add a new record
> - Delete a record
> - Search data bound to the `GridView`
> - Display detailed information about selected records in the `GridView`
>
> For adding new records, I'm using a
>   dialog or other similar jQuery plugin.
>   For deleting records, I'm making a
>   full postback to refresh data after a
>   confirmation dialog and sometimes I'm
>   putting the target `GridView` in an
>   ASP.NET `UpdatePanel` to prevent full
>   postback. When searching for data, I
>   have to make a full postback. I think I
>   have no way of doing this action
>   without postback (consider a complex
>   `GridView`.) And for displaying more
>   detailed information about the current
>   record without postback, I have 2 ways:
>
> 1. Loading an ASP.NET user control asynchronously - but with regard to
>      [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5519450/postback-in-loaded-asp-net-usercontrol-with-jquery) thread, I'm not able to do
>      server-side actions with postback.
> 2. If, for example, I want to display a `ListBox` and a `TreeView` about a
>      record in a jQuery dialog, I put them
>      in an `UpdatePanel` and write binding
>      codes in a hidden server side button.
>      Then I'm triggering the click event of
>      the binding button in the OnOpen event
>      of the jQuery Dialog. My software is
>      running locally so I don't care about
>      SEO.
>
> As I'm a novice programmer, please share your expriences with me,
>   tell me where I'm wrong (maybe
>   everywhere!) and where I can improve.
>   Thanks.